# Complex Count: count opportunities for aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle11g, inventory-management, logistics

I am struggling how to get the output I need to provide for a report.  I am trying to show what products(LPN) I can combine, to free up space in a warehouse and how many of these opportunities there are.  The below code pulls all the data I need but I can't seem to figure out how to summarize how many opportunities to consolidate.

```
WITH ITEM AS
(
  SELECT IC.ITEM_NAME,COUNT(*) 
  FROM PARCEL_ID L 
  JOIN PARCEL_DETAIL LD ON L.LPN_ID=LD.LPN_ID
  JOIN LOCN LH ON LH.LOCN_ID=L.CURR_SUB_LOCN_ID AND LH.LOCN_CLASS='R' AND 
LH.PULL_ZONE='RSV'
  JOIN RESV_LOCN RLH ON RLH.LOCN_ID=L.CURR_SUB_LOCN_ID
  JOIN ITEM_C IC ON IC.ITEM_ID=LD.ITEM_ID
  WHERE L.LPN_FACILITY_STATUS='30' AND LD.SIZE_VALUE <'30' GROUP BY 
IC.ITEM_NAME HAVING COUNT(*)>'1'
  )
SELECT L.TC_LPN_ID,LD.SIZE_VALUE,LH.DSP_LOCN,L.ACTUAL_VOLUME,L.WEIGHT, 
IC.ITEM_NAME,RLH.MAX_VOL,RLH.MAX_WT 
FROM PARCEL L 
JOIN PARCEL_DETAIL LD ON L.LPN_ID=LD.LPN_ID
JOIN LOCN LH ON LH.LOCN_ID=L.CURR_SUB_LOCN_ID AND LH.LOCN_CLASS='R' AND 
LH.PULL_ZONE ='RSV'
JOIN RESV_LOCN RLH ON RLH.LOCN_ID=L.CURR_SUB_LOCN_ID
JOIN ITEM_C IC ON IC.ITEM_ID=LD.ITEM_ID
WHERE L.LPN_FACILITY_STATUS='30' AND LD.SIZE_VALUE <'30' AND IC.ITEM_NAME IN 
(SELECT ITEM_NAME FROM ITEM)
```

The data returned is a list showing any product which is stored in multiple reserve locations and need to be consolidated. Looking like the below.

```
        LPN|Qty|Loc|Volume|Weight|Item Name| Max Vol | Max Wt
         1 | 12|1  |  25  | 15   | ABC123  |   500   |   250
         2 | 25|2  |  300 | 150  | ABC123  |   500   |   250
         3 | 25|3  |  125 | 100  | DEF123  |   750   |   250
         4 | 35|4  |  350 | 250  | DEF123  |   750   |   350
```

Is there a way to summarize the the number of opportunities for reserve location consolidation?  In the above example there are 2 opportunities because we have 2 item names that will not exceed max volume or max weight for either location if combined. There is a second issue where there could be multiple opportunities for the same item name to be combined. How can I accomplish this, using either my current query or as a separate query referencing the result of what I currently have (I am adding this to a Cognos report so I can use a separate object).

I apologize if this is not the place for advice like this but I would appreciate any direction you might be able to offer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of how the data looks before you want to pivot it?